# Unimaginable speed of sockets into Oracle JVM

Tags: java, oracle, sockets, jvm

I'm working with Oracle and I'm asked to speed up some legacy application. For this speedup I'm in need of some in-memory singleton containing temporary data; currently these data are stored into database permanent tables and it imposes much load to database. Temporary tables cannot be used due to multi-session access to data.

I tried to make this singleton using stored Java. Main problem I found - Oracle makes something like separate JVM for every database session (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chtwo.htm#BABBDCDI), so singleton cannot be accessed via common memory.

I makes some API containting "server" (singleton) and "client" (access methods). Client communicates with server via local sockets. Because single-threaded nature of stored Java (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chtwo.htm#BABHHHDG) server accepts and processes requests into a single thread like this (simplified):

```
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(..., InetAddress.getByName(null));
    while (!finished) {
      Socket client = socket.accept();
      ..
      output.println(process(input));
      ..
      client.close();
    }
```

Client sends request like this:

```
  Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(null), getPort(requestId));
  ..
  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) output.println(data[i]);
  String result = in.readLine();
  ..
  socket.close();
```

While runnings tests as a stand-alone Java application, without Oracle, it works like this on my workstation:

> 34001 calls served at 3.178 sec.
>
> Avg. 10698.86721208307 calls per second
>
> Avg. wait time: 0.03199905885121026 ms.
>
> Avg. process time: 0.0628510926149231 ms.

It's generally acceptable. But when loading into Oracle, such test shows a very different speed:

> 117 calls served at 24.218 sec.
>
> Avg. 4.831117350730861 calls per second
>
> Avg. wait time: 90.17094017094017 ms.
>
> Avg. process time: 203.54700854700855 ms.

Why it's so slow? What can I do to repair this nonsense? Is there better way to communicate between sessions in Oracle/jvm?

Comment: Slowness is likely a "you-problem" or more specifically a problem of your specific environment and as such it is hard to say what to do when there is nothing to actually go on. No configuration details, no environment description, no nothing. For all we know you're running the database in a virtual machine with the I/O throughput severely limited. You also don't detail what you are communicating between the databases, so it is also impossible to give any advice about what might be a better strategy (plus that is opinionated). Oracle Advanced Queuing comes to mind, as a wild guess.

Comment: The OS the oracle DB runs under also has a lot of bearing on performance.  Your data as presented does not mean much in terms of getting help or suggestions.  Do you have perf stats for the OS - I/O queue request lengths, etc.?   This clearly looks like a possible OS or listener issue.  Check the listener log on the oracle machine.

Comment: Does your latest attempt still use Java on the database server? What is the value of the java_pool_size parameter?

Comment: Thank you. I guessed it's my problem but now it really looks like environment problem. Measured in several environments, it shows speed from 15'000 standalone / 5'000 Oracle (my home computer) via 250-500 Oracle (some our servers) to 4-5 Oracle (extreme case on two our servers). So our DBAs will research cause of it.

Answer (score 1):

As a result of investigation.

1. Administrators said nothing interesting about i/o quests requests length etc.
2. Oracle's internal java is several times slower than stand-alone one. I wrote a simple example, in which converts integer to string and put it into map; it works about to 4 time slower in stored procedure. Penalty is different for various operations.
3. I profiled class. Using different techniques (nodelay, reusing sockets, threading) I reached about to 8 times faster in stand-alone application and about to 100 times faster in stored Java, it was limit I can do.
4. At this moment I refused of stored-java-only. I started an stand-alone application with server part near the database and set up client part into database to connect it. It grants me speed I required; in such case effective speed is about 80% of stand-alone application. This speed is enough for me; it stopped to be a bottleneck.